# how to get boolean value from an array which contains array and objects as elements

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to get a boolean value from an array of array and object like below

```
points = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  {a:1, b:2}
]
```

now, I get some array or object from server,

```
let newVal = [1,2,3,4]
or sometimes 
let newVal = {a: 2, b: 5}  etc
```

And I need to check whether it's present inside `points` or not and push inside it if absent.

```
 if(!_.some(points, val => _.isEqual(val,newVal))){
    points.push(newVal)
 } else return;
```

**expected result**
if `newVal` is present inside `points` then I should get `true` else `false`

But the above `_some` always returns true if `newVal` is array.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz please have a look

Comment: Try `points.some(val => _.isEqual(val,newVal))` instead of `_.some(points, val => _.isEqual(val,newVal))`.  The built-in `some` should do what you need.

Comment: @user2740650 yeah it's working

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on `isEqual` from `lodash` to determine equality, you can use this:

```js
points.some(val => isEqual(val, newVal))
```

Example snippet below:

```html
<script type="module">

import {isEqual} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.min.js';

// returns `true` if value was added, `false` otherwise
function addNewValueIfNotEqual (arr, value) {
  if (arr.some(v => isEqual(v, value))) return false;
  arr.push(value);
  return true;
}

const points = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  {a:1, b:2},
];

const newValues = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  {a: 2, b: 5},
];

for (const value of newValues) {
  const valueAdded = addNewValueIfNotEqual(points, value);
  console.log({value, valueAdded});
}

console.log(points);

</script>
```